# Build navbar for angular 4 app using bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have seen the documentation for ng-bootstrap. In that i have read this point:

**Should I add bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to my project?
No, the goal of ng-bootstrap is to completely replace JavaScript implementation for components. Nor should you include other dependencies like jQuery or popper.js. It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code.**

But now to implement the bootstrap topnav i have to include bootstrap 4 supporting javascript files.
If i am doing that i am **not following** the words said in ng-bootstrap. Need suggestions.

Comment: As @Veromy say you don't need bootstrap, only css. You can see an implementation of navbar in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/738. NOTE:If you want to import only css you can write "npm install bootstrap-css-only" or include in your html or  downloaded and include in styles in the .angular-cli.json

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

After installing `bootstrap` via `npm` with `$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` you can simply add the library in your `angular-cli.json` like this:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

And it should then work.

Comment: this seems working fine. i got the view of the top navbar by adding the css file and i have added bootstrap beta 2 using CLI. But now i have got another problem. In the mobile view the nav bar is not getting collapsed. on click of the breadcrumb button it is not showing them the menu. and when i tried to see that using developer tools i have realized that the "collapse" class is not getting added to the breadcrumb button. then i even tried to add bootstrap.min.js (just a wild try) even that did not work. I dont know why it is happening.

Comment: and in console its throwing me an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import any javascript files in order to use ng-bootstrap.

Running `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` should be sufficient.

It is even possible to use bootstrap4 without ng-bootstrap, if you just need it for the styling.

Comment: Hi @venomy i have tried this already but this did not work. When i tried to add this "https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/". I did not get anything. Upto my knowledge ng-bootstrap is just for the bootstrap components.

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not realize you only needed the CSS. In this case I think @Manu 's solution should work. And you should make sure you have the right classes on your navbar. Keep in mind some functions of the bootstrap are not yet available in Angular